# The LINQ expression OrderBy DateTimeOffset.DateTime could not be translated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, graphql, automapper

I have a .NET Core project in which I have implemented this GraphQL query. The query works correctly, but the sorting by date is not working.

```cs
[UsePaging(MaxPageSize = 200, IncludeTotalCount = true)]
[UseProjection]
[UseFiltering]
[UseSorting]
public async Task<IQueryable<UserDto>> UserMetadatas(string myValue, [Service] ActivityEngineDataContext context,[Service] IMapper mapper)
{
  var entities = context.Users.Where(act => act.MyValue== myValue);
  return entities.ProjectTo<UserDto>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
}
```

Using AutoMapper, I have created the following projection to map the entity with the DTO.

```cs
CreateProjection<User, UserDto>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.CreationDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.CreationDate.DateTime))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.LastUpdateDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.LastUpdateDate.DateTime));
```

I had to create this projection because the properties of the User class are DateTimeOffset type, whereas the properties of the UserDto class are DateTime type.

When I run this query from the Banana Cake Pop playground

```json
query{
  activityInstancesMetadata(
    myValue: "value"
    where: {and: [{status: {eq: 32}}]}
    order: {lastUpdateDate: ASC}
    first: 20
  ) {
    nodes {
      creationDate
      lastUpdateDate
      id
      status
    }
    totalCount
  }
}
```

I have this error:

```
"The LINQ expression 'DbSet<User>()
.Where(a => a.MyValue== __myValue_0)
.OrderBy(a => a.LastUpdateDate.DateTime)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.<VisitMethodCall>g__CheckTranslated|15_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated, <>c__DisplayClass15_0& )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at HotChocolate.Types.Pagination.QueryableCursorPagingHandler`1.ResolveAsync(IResolverContext context, IQueryable`1 source, CursorPagingArguments arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at HotChocolate.Types.Pagination.CursorPagingHandler.HotChocolate.Types.Pagination.IPagingHandler.SliceAsync(IResolverContext context, Object source)
   at HotChocolate.Types.Pagination.PagingMiddleware.InvokeAsync(IMiddlewareContext context)
   at HotChocolate.Utilities.MiddlewareCompiler`1.ExpressionHelper.AwaitTaskHelper(Task task)
   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.Tasks.ResolverTask.ExecuteResolverPipelineAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at HotChocolate.Execution.Processing.Tasks.ResolverTask.TryExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
```

Reading the stack trace and debugging, it seems that the issue is caused by Entity Framework, which, within the OrderBy method, inserts the expression set in the ForMember method of the Projection.

### What I have tried so far

- Set the conversion in the DataContext, in this way

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
  {
    var properties = entityType.ClrType.GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTimeOffset)
                                                                || p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTimeOffset?));
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
      modelBuilder
          .Entity(entityType.Name)
          .Property(property.Name)
          .HasConversion(new DateTimeOffsetToStringConverter());
    }
  }
}
```

- Double cast in the projection

```cs
CreateProjection<User, UserDto>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.CreationDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => (DateTime)(object)s.CreationDate))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.LastUpdateDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => (DateTime)(object)s.LastUpdateDate));
```

This code works, but I encounter other issues when I invoke the query that returns a single record.

Is there a way to resolve this issue without using "ToList" in the query?

Note: this is not a duplicate of [EF Core query only DateTime of DateTimeOffset cannot be translated;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69743408/ef-core-query-only-datetime-of-datetimeoffset-cannot-be-translated) I tried to implement that solution, but in this scenario it's not good

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69743408/8017690. Maybe use the "double cast" part of your code without the "Set the conversion in the DataContext" part?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EF Core query only DateTime of DateTimeOffset cannot be translated;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69743408/ef-core-query-only-datetime-of-datetimeoffset-cannot-be-translated)

Comment: @YongShun I tried using the two solutions both one at a time and together but without success.
The (DateTime)(object) cast works, but using it, the query that returns a single element no longer works.

Comment: The cast doesn't work, that's why you have this problem. The cast itself is a very, VERY bad idea because it tries to cast a DateTime with a *specific* offset to some random timezone. Is that UTC? Local summer time? Local winter time? You have no idea, you're just guessing. That alone can result in bad data and incorrect query results.

Comment: Why is this cast used? Even a human developer couldn't guess what this tries to do - convert to UTC? Some other offset? If `local time`, whose local time? The database's, the GraphQL server's or the API client's?

Comment: Is all this an attempt to fix some perceived HotChocolate issues with DateTimeOffset? Are you sure there's anything to fix? HotChocolate's [DateTimeType](https://github.com/ChilliCream/graphql-platform/blob/a090dab523d3157be1733b3febdb58f0c5d37aec/src/HotChocolate/Core/src/Types/Types/Scalars/DateTimeType.cs) uses a DateTimeOffset itself. The name `DateTimeType` is used because that's the name used in the GraphQL spec. What happens when you remove `ForMember` completely? If `User` and `UserDTO` have the same properties, what happens if you remove mapping completely?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Removing ForMember, I have an error "Unable to create map for..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I don't know if there are simpler solutions, but at the moment it's the only solution I've found. I hope it can help someone.
I implemented an interceptor that executes the order by before carrying out the select, in this way the sorting is carried out on the entity and not on the dto. As a result, Entity Framework does not use the expression specified in the mapping's .ForMember() to perform sorting.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MyProject.Common
{
  public class OrderByDateTimeOffsetQueryInterceptor : IQueryExpressionInterceptor
  {
    private static readonly MethodInfo _orderByMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod(
      name: nameof(Queryable.OrderBy),
      bindingAttr: BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
      types: new[]
      {
        typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0)),
        typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(
          Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0),
          Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(1)))
      })!;

    private static readonly MethodInfo _orderByDescendingMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod(
      name: nameof(Queryable.OrderByDescending),
      bindingAttr: BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,
      types: new[]
      {
        typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0)),
        typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(
          Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0),
          Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(1)))
      })!;

    private readonly ILogger<OrderByDateTimeOffsetQueryInterceptor> _logger;

    public Expression QueryCompilationStarting(Expression queryExpression, QueryExpressionEventData eventData)
    {
      return OrderByExpressionVisitor.Instance.Visit(queryExpression);
    }


    private class OrderByExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
      public static readonly OrderByExpressionVisitor Instance = new();

      protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
      {
        if (!node.Method.IsGenericMethod)
          return base.VisitMethodCall(node);

        if (node.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition() != _orderByMethod && node.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition() != _orderByDescendingMethod)
          return base.VisitMethodCall(node);

        Debug.Assert(node.Arguments[1].NodeType is ExpressionType.Quote);
        LambdaExpression keySelector = (LambdaExpression)((UnaryExpression)node.Arguments[1]).Operand;

        if (keySelector.Body is not MemberExpression { Member: PropertyInfo property } || property.PropertyType != typeof(DateTime))
          return base.VisitMethodCall(node);

        return new SelectExpressionVisitor(property.Name, node.Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition()).Visit(node.Arguments[0]);
      }
    }

    private class SelectExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
      private readonly string _propertyName;
      private readonly MethodInfo _methodInfo;

      public SelectExpressionVisitor(string propertyName, MethodInfo method)
      {
        _propertyName = propertyName;
        _methodInfo = method;
      }

      protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
      {
        if (node.Method.Name != nameof(Queryable.Select))
          return base.VisitMethodCall(node);

        Type sourceType = node.Arguments[0].Type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        PropertyInfo? dateTimeOffsetProperty = sourceType.GetProperty(
          name: _propertyName,
          bindingAttr: BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
          binder: null,
          returnType: typeof(DateTimeOffset),
          types: Type.EmptyTypes,
          modifiers: null);

        if (dateTimeOffsetProperty is null)
          return base.VisitMethodCall(node);

        ParameterExpression sourceParam = Expression.Parameter(sourceType, "source");
        LambdaExpression keySelector = Expression.Lambda(
          body: Expression.Property(
            expression: sourceParam,
            propertyName: _propertyName),
          parameters: sourceParam);

        return node.Update(node.Object, new Expression[]
        {
          Expression.Call(
            instance: null,
            method: _methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(sourceType, typeof(DateTimeOffset)),
            arg0: node.Arguments[0],
            arg1: Expression.Quote(keySelector)),
          node.Arguments[1]
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code could be improved, perhaps by injecting AutoMapper (currently it only works if the DTO and entity properties have the same name), but at the moment I think I'll adopt this solution.